# hotkey does not close Seleinum Webdriver session when pressed (python)

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop, automation, hotkeys

im practically a fetus when it comes to python programming and i hope some of you gods would be able to help me. basically i have a loop set up that pulls values from a website but i need it run indefinitely until i press the specified hotkey which is q, the loop runs and pulls the data needed, but whenever i press q, the loop simply keeps running and i have to close the browser manually.

here is the piece of code in question:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import keyboard

PATH = r"C:\Users\username"
options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
ser = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
cweb = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)

class Coin:
    def __init__(self, coinname, datasource):
         self.coinname = coinname
         self.datasource = datasource
    
    def pulldata(self):
         self.values = []
         time.sleep(5)
         cweb.get(self.datasource)
         time.sleep(5)
         
         price = cweb.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span')
         percent = cweb.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span')
         upordown = cweb.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span/span')
         caret = upordown.get_attribute('class')
    
         if caret == 'icon-Caret-up':
             daychange = ('' + percent.text)

         elif caret == 'icon-Caret-down':
             daychange2 = ('-' + percent.text)

         vol = cweb.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div')
         mkcap = cweb.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div')
         circsupply = cweb.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]')
         self.values.append(price.text) 
       
         if caret == 'icon-Caret-up':
               self.values.append(daychange)
         elif caret == 'icon-Caret-down':
               self.values.append(daychange2)

         self.values.append(vol.text)
         self.values.append(mkcap.text)
         self.values.append(circsupply.text)
         print(self.values)

def kill_chromedriver():   
  for proc in psutil.process_iter():
       if proc.name() == "chromedriver.exe":
            proc.kill()
       if proc.name() == "chrome.exe":
            proc.kill()
 
         
while True:
   btc = Coin('Bitcoin','https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/')
   btc.pulldata()
   btc2 = Coin('Bitcoin','https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/tether/')
   btc2.pulldata()

   if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        kill_chromedriver()
        break
```

print('done reading')

so how do i edit this code, so that the driver closes and the loop stops on command?
ive tried positioning the break statement in different places, and also placing the cweb.close() function out of the loops. ill continue running through other options. i would be extremely grateful for any tips or help.

edits: took some help from an extremely useful lad, but it seems as if pressing the hotkey is recognized by the computer and python, but not recognized by selenium or the browser session itself.
wish i knew more about code like yall do lmao

G-man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found .quit() to fail sometimes with selenium. You can use psutil instead. Call this function in the `if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):` block.

```
import psutil

def kill_chromedriver():   
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == "chromedriver.exe":
            proc.kill()
```

Edit: I think your issue might be related to read_key() not executing until the data are pulled. I tested this on my cpu in Jupyter and it worked.

```
while True:
    btc = Coin('Bitcoin','https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/')
    btc.pulldata()
    btc2 = Coin('Bitcoin','https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/tether/')
    btc2.pulldata()

    print("You can press q now.")
    if keyboard.read_key() == "q":
       
        kill_chromedriver()
        break
```

Comment: so the function you gave me works perfectly but it doesnt trigger when i press q. ill experiment and try to see why that is.

Comment: GUESS WHAT!?? i was playing around a bit. the function works perfectly in the while loop. turns out theres a problem w using q as a hotkey. probably wasnt coding it right with the module or something. your a genius lol thanks for the help fr. also taught me a little bit too so thank you fr i hope you win the lottery

Comment: Glad it works for you. In lieu of the lottery, I'd settle for you marking this as the accepted answer and an upvote. ; )

Comment: Additionally, I highly recommend using the cmc api. Your xpath method is prone to breaking if there are web UI changes. https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/

Comment: aight so turns out it doesnt work and i  thought it worked after i removed an argument from the function. which resulted in the loop going once and then dying immediately for reasons i cannot understand. ill keep trying to see what i can do

Comment: Add your updated code with a post edit or create another question if you need more assistance.

Comment: i have plans to switch over to using the API but costs a little bit of money for the amount of data im trying to acquire

Comment: See my edit Gabe.

Comment: THANK YOUUUUU!! it works perfectly now. thank you so much for your help fr i think i got what i wanted